# PHP files uploader not working

Tags: php

I have tried everythink. When I want upload foto on my server, name is write to db,but nothing  uploaded to server.

**HTML**

```
<form role="form" action="db_work.php?index=list_slider&action=new" method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000"/>
```

**PHP**

```
   $targetFolder = 'uploads/foto/slider'; // Relative to the root
            $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
            $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
            $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

            // Validate the file type
            $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
            $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
            $fileName = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
            $fileName = strtolower ($fileName);

            $mysqli->query("UPDATE list_slider SET item_file = '$fileName' WHERE id='$id'");

            if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
                move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
                echo '1';
            } else {
                echo 'Invalid file type.';
            }
```

this script is in folder admin. And in the root is folder uploads.

Comment: What's the result of `if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes))`

Comment: p.s. the way you're handling the upload is EXTREMELY unsecure.

Comment: Make sure you have error display and reporting turned on. E.g. `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: I have it .. $targetFolder = 'uploads/foto/slider'; There is error. '/uploads/foto/slider' is correct

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lan="en">
<head>
<title>Upload Script</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<table align="center" width="60%">
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center">
<h2>Upload Image</h2>
</td>
</tr>
<input type="hidden" name="insert" value="updetails" />
<tr>
<td><label for="photo">Upload Image</label></td>
<td width="5%">:</td>
<td><input name="uploadimage" type="file" id="photo" /></td>
</tr>
<tr height="20"> </tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center">
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

uploader.php

```
if($_POST['submit']=='Upload')
{
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

    $info = pathinfo($_FILES['uploadimage']['name']);
    $ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file

    $target_path = "uploads/";
    $target_path = $target_path.str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES["uploadimage"]["name"]);

    if ((($_FILES["uploadimage"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["uploadimage"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["uploadimage"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["uploadimage"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["uploadimage"]["type"] == "image/x-png")|| ($_FILES["uploadimage"]["type"] == "image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["uploadimage"]["size"] < 5242880) && in_array($ext, $allowedExts))  //5242880 Maximum File size in bytes (5mb)
    {
        if ($_FILES["uploadimage"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["uploadimage"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name'], $target_path);

            echo "<br />The image ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadimage']['name'])." has been uploaded";

        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
}
else
{
    echo"<br /><b>You Dont have permission to open this Page</b>";
}
```

Comment: You Can Write to db on successful uploading to server by adding db insert at if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name'], $target_path)){Db Insert Statement...}

Comment: You are using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. There might be some server's root directory permission issue.. So it is better to use relative path to upload file.